# Importing text files without column name into database table

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I have an empty table "BTS" with three columns in sql server

and a delimited text file with data(No Column Name,only row data)

I want to import data from text file to "BTS"

While I am trying this using import export wizard in ssms ,it is trying to take first row of text file as column names,what should I do to get rid of this?

Comment: As of my knowledge ur saying to import data from flat file???

Comment: Yes,Flat file obviously :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While importing data in table through ssms,

In data source tab where as you will be selecting the flat file to import,please uncheck the option"column names in the first data row"
which will not read the column name